# Why is the output "false10" and not "false11"?

Tags: java

Could someone tell me why the value of a is not changing in the following code?

```
int a = 10;
System.out.print( (a < 5) && (++a==11));
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing "short circuit evaluation" in action. The second part of the boolean expression `(++a==11)` is never evaluated, because `(a < 5)` is false. In this case, the JVM knows that the whole expression is false before it evaluates `(++a==11)`, so it skips it entirely.

This is also a great example of why such "side effects" are bad in logical tests: you're mutating the values you're evaluating in an unpredictable way. In a non-trivial program, you don't necessarily know whether `(a < 5)` is true, so it's difficult to know whether `a` will be incremented or not.

Comment: Please just vote to close duplicate questions instead of wasting your time answering them. :)

Comment: Ironically, there is a comment on the most popular answer on the question this duplicates complaining that that one is a duplicate... to repeat the reply: "I don't have time to search for duplicates of questions asked by other people, so I only close as duplicate if I know a specific question that this is a duplicate of. Otherwise, answering often takes much less time." :)

We can certainly all help keep the site clean and free of duplicates, and we can also answer the question.

Comment: The duplicate answers the question. you could spend your time answering an already answered question... or you can help someone who doesn't have an answer.